# When creating a small farm search topology, does the web application get created on the Central Admin server or the other server?

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search, server-farm, topology

I'm fairly new to Sharepoint and I'm trying to set up a small farm search topology such as the following: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750251(v=office.14).aspx .  I don't believe I set it up right, however.  I have two servers - we'll call them SPCrawl and SPSearch.  According to the guide linked above, the SPCrawl server should host Central Admin and perform the crawling.  I believe I messed up because I created the web application on SPCrawl, but then created the Enterprise Search Center and linked it to the web application on SPCrawl.

Basically, my question is this: should I have created the web application on SPSearch instead?  I'm just wondering because unless I'm misinterpreting something, it doesn't seem like SPSearch is actually doing anything.  I just want confirmation before changing anything.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If hardware on all server are same then it really doesnot matter, You can change the server role.

Central Admin will host on the 1st server in the farm( on which you run the Config wizard & create config db).

By default all web apps created on the Central Admin server but you can change the AAM to change it to different server.Once you created the Web Application just Change the AAM setting then you all set.

Comment: So you're saying as of right now, EVERYTHING is running on my SPCrawl server including the web front-end search?  In order to change this, I just need to modify the AAM setting?  If that's the case, do you know of a good guide for this?

Comment: yes, everything is running on SPcrawl server unless you select the different. For AAM, 1st you need a DNS(if you dont want to use the server name and port number), which points to your WFE.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/25/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx